# How to getting relationship keys

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, restkit

Sorry for english :( .... I know do coding simple json with restkit. But very confusing json is like below.

```
 {
    "success": {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "Message"
    },
    "customers": [
        {
            "customerId": "182",
            "customerName": "anil",
            "email": "anil@yahoo.com",
            "customerAbout": "To show the customer details",
            "customerLogoSmall": "http://server.com/ thumb/1.jpg",
            "customerLogoLarge": "http://server.com/ 2.jpg",
            "ratingPoint": "10",
            "address": "adress of customer",
.
.
.
            "openingHour": [
                {
                    "day": "monday",
                    "morning": "10to12.30",
                    "evening": "1to6",
                    "customerId": "182"
                },
                {
                    "day": "sunday",
                    "morning": "",
                    "evening": "",
                    "customerId": "182"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "customerId": "183",
            "customerName": "miche",
            "email": "babu@yahoo.com",
            "customerAbout": "To show the customer details",
            "customerLogoSmall": "http://server.com/ thumb/1.jpg",
            "customerLogoLarge": "http://server.com/ 2.jpg",
            "ratingPoint": "10",
.
.
.
            "openingHour": [
                {
                    "day": "monday",
                    "morning": "10to12.30",
                    "evening": "1to6",
                    "customerId": "183"
                },
                {
                    "day": "sunday",
                    "morning": "",
                    "evening": "",
                    "customerId": "183"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "allCustomers": [
        {
            "customerId": "182"
        },
        {
            "customerId": "183"
        }
    ]
}
```

//CheckInCustomerOpeningHour.h (For 'openingHour' key)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class CheckInCustomers;
@interface CheckInCustomerOpeningHour : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * customerId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * evening;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * morning;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CheckInCustomers *openHourrelationship;
@end
```

//CheckInCustomers.h (For 'customers' key)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class CheckInCustomerOpeningHour;
@interface CheckInCustomers : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * alreadyRated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * alreadyRatedMessage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * avgCustomerRating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * bonusProgram;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * colourCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contactNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * customerAbout;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * customerId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * customerLogoLarge;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * customerLogoSmall;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * customerName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * distanceToShop;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationLongitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * numberOfCustomerRating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * offerCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rateLater;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * ratingPoint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CheckInCustomerOpeningHour *customerRelationShip;
@end
```

//CheckInAllCustomers.h (For 'allCustomers' key)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface CheckInAllCustomers : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * customerId;
@end
```

//Mapping code

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[OPRestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];

    RKObjectMapping *success_Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[checkInSuccess class]];
    [success_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"code" toAttribute:@"code"];
    [success_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"message" toAttribute:@"message"];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:success_Mapping forKeyPath:@"success"];

    
    RKManagedObjectMapping *openingHour_Mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CheckInCustomerOpeningHour class]
                                                                     inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    openingHour_Mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"customerId";
    [openingHour_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerId" toAttribute:@"customerId"];
    [openingHour_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"day" toAttribute:@"day"];
    [openingHour_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"evening" toAttribute:@"evening"];
    [openingHour_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"morning" toAttribute:@"morning"];
    

    RKObjectMapping *hour_Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[checkInOpeningHour class]];
    [hour_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"openingHour" toRelationship:@"openingHourData" withMapping:openingHour_Mapping];

    
    RKManagedObjectMapping *getCustomer_Mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CheckInCustomers class]
                                                                     inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    getCustomer_Mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"customerId";
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerId" toAttribute:@"customerId"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"address" toAttribute:@"address"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"alreadyRated" toAttribute:@"alreadyRated"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"alreadyRatedMessage" toAttribute:@"alreadyRatedMessage"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"avgCustomerRating" toAttribute:@"avgCustomerRating"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"bonusProgram" toAttribute:@"bonusProgram"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"colourCode" toAttribute:@"colourCode"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"contactNumber" toAttribute:@"contactNumber"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerAbout" toAttribute:@"customerAbout"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerLogoLarge" toAttribute:@"customerLogoLarge"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerLogoSmall" toAttribute:@"customerLogoSmall"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerName" toAttribute:@"customerName"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"distanceToShop" toAttribute:@"distanceToShop"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"location" toAttribute:@"location"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"locationLatitude" toAttribute:@"locationLatitude"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"locationLongitude" toAttribute:@"locationLongitude"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"numberOfCustomerRating" toAttribute:@"numberOfCustomerRating"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"offerCount" toAttribute:@"offerCount"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"rateLater" toAttribute:@"rateLater"];
    [getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"openingHour" toRelationship:@"customerRelationShip" withMapping:openingHour_Mapping];
    
    

    RKManagedObjectMapping *getAllCustomer_Mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CheckInAllCustomers class]
                                                                     inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    [getAllCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customerId" toAttribute:@"customerId"];
    
    RKObjectMapping *c_Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[checkInRoot class]];
    [c_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"customers" toRelationship:@"customersData" withMapping:getCustomer_Mapping];
    [c_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"allCustomers" toRelationship:@"allCustomersData" withMapping:getAllCustomer_Mapping];
    
    [objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:c_Mapping withRootKeyPath:@""];
```

Output will get 'success','customers' and 'allCustomers' But 'openingHour' value is NULL.

```
[getCustomer_Mapping mapKeyPath:@"openingHour" toRelationship:@"customerRelationShip" withMapping:openingHour_Mapping];
```

is correct like above code? I dnt know that how to getting values of "openingHour' key. Plz help me

## EDIT:

Let me Explain How it Works:

- Above the json is getting from our server. All Keys are need to save into coredata.
- 'success' key is object not array. it will save 'checkInSuccess' class object But no need coredata.
- 'customers' key is array. It will save to coredata with 'CheckInCustomers' object.
- 'allCustomers' key is another array. It will save to coredata with 'CheckInAllCustomers' object.
- 'openingHour' key is an array. we need to save to core data.
- I used code that will not save to coredata with 'checkInOpeningHour' object. That is problem.
- I want to know How to save 'openingHour' array in coredata??

Comment: How, you are parsing your JSON, using something like SBJson, or something??

Comment: Does RSKit Returns NSDictionary after parsing the JSON??

Comment: @rptwsthi Yes... Any problem?

Comment: Great No problem infacr problem solve:

Comment: But customerRelationShip getting is NULL. infacr?

Answer (score 0):

See How it Works:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [yourParser parse: jsonString];
for (int i= 0; i < [[dictionary valueForKey:@"customers"] count]; i++) {
    NSArray *openingHourArray = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"customers"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey: openingHour];

    for(int j = 0; j <[openingHourArray count]; j++){
        NSDictionary *openingHourDictionary = [openingHourArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"openingHourDictionary =%@", openingHourDictionary);
    }

}
```

here a homework for for you, check if values returned by `valueForKey` is dict or array, accordingly. Otherwise it'll lead to application crash. 
Happy Coading.. :)

Comment: What is that.. Never that we are use. I need to storing to coredata getting value key is 'openingHour'

Comment: By this how you are able to get that opening hour dictionary, from your Dictionary of JSON Data. If it doesn't help, then Please explain what you actually want, IN Detail.

Comment: Do u know RestKit? If Yes I will explain

Comment: Explain It for others.. :)

Comment: OK.. Above the json is getting from our server. All Keys are need to save into coredata. 'success' key is object not array.  it will save 'checkInSuccess' class object But no need coredata. 'customers' key is array. it will save to coredata with 'CheckInCustomers' object. 'allCustomers' key is another array. it will save to coredata with 'CheckInAllCustomers' object. 'openingHour' key is an array. we need to save to coredata. i used code that willnt save to coredata with 'checkInOpeningHour' object. that is problem. I need How to saving to coredata for 'openingHour' array.

Comment: Plz help me. It is important of my work. Understand any my word?

Comment: Sorry Everyone. Above my code is correct. Some problem of a line in my another code. that fixed.